# Using excel to reference other workbooks, but using a cell to tell excel which other workbook to reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am trying to input data into a cell, and have the cell next to it reference data in a separate file to tell if if there is a match in a specific column in that other file. The goal is to use this master sheet to check multiple other files for matching data. For instance here is how I would like it to work:

Input a file path into cell C1. In Cell A1, I will type a word like "Cow". Cell B1 will report "Yes" or "No" based on if "Cow" is found in Column E of the other file from C1.

I've been trying to use Vlookup with Indirect to do this, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. 

Please add some context to your question such as images of the master and source workbooks and the formulas you've tried so far and their results.